# File readline adds excess symbol

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I have a `*.dat` file with one string  - `localhost`

a try to read this string and set host name

```
QFile file("file.dat");
if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    char buf[1024];
    qint64 lineLength = file.readLine(buf, sizeof(buf));
    QDebug() << buf;
    if (lineLength != -1) {
        db.setHostName(buf);
    }
}
```

I expected result of `QDebug` is: `localhost`, but I see a `"localhost`, with one quote.
Also `setHostName` doesn't work because of the excess symbol - quote.

Why does the quote appear?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my Windows machine with a file that contains a string. No extra quote detected.

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to use QFile just to manipulate a tiny file? Why not use the STL?

Comment: @JonathanMee   https://drive.google.com/a/frtk.ru/file/d/0BxNqSglDPL20MDdiUW5IRjhncFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @koch_kir I concur with [vahancho](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2674506/vahancho) I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @JonathanMee I think because you should add afore this code `QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");`

Comment: @koch_kir That line should have nothing to do with this problem. If you believe them to be related I'd recommend that you comment the line out and see if the problem persists.